# Передача функции в качестве параметра другой функции

Tags: javascript, функции, параметры

Каким образом можно передать функцию в качестве параметра для другой функции? делаю так, однако выдает ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError (

```
function sun() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    console.log(x);
    return x;
}

function mult(sun()) {
    var x = 5 + sun();
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
function mult(sun()) {
  var x = 5 + sun();
  console.log(x);
}
```

Ошибка возникает из-за некорректного определения. В этом коде вы **определяете** новую функцию **mult**. При этом в круглых скобках должны указываться **формальные параметры**, а не конкретные аргументы, как у вас. Конкретные аргументы (будь то обычное значение или функция) будут передаваться в будущем, во время **вызова** созданной вами функции. На стадии **определения** функции указывается формальный параметр на место которого будет **подставлено** конкретное значение во время **вызова** этой функции. При этом формальный параметр должен иметь обыкновенное имя, например, **par**, **num** или любое другое подходящее. Вы же в определении функции пытаетесь сделать вызов  формального параметра **sun()**, что не имеет смысла и приводит к ошибке.

Если хотите иметь возможность передавать одну функцию в другую, то для начала эти функции нужно опередить, а затем уже передать при вызове, например так:

```js
function sun() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    console.log(x);
    return x;
}

function mult(func) {
    var x = 5 + func();
    console.log(x);
}

// при вызове на место формального параметра func будет
// подставлен фактический аргумент-функция sun
 mult(sun);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Приятно видеть человека, который в первом же ответе показывает хороший стиль ответов.

Comment: @AK, приветствую, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```js
function sun() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}

function mult(f) {
  var x = 5 + f();
  console.log(x);
}

mult(sun);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно

```js
function sun() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  return x;
}

function mult(y) {
  var x = 5 + y;
  console.log(x)
}

var y = sun();

mult(y)
```

Answer (score -1):

Функции в js, в отличии от других языков, это обычные строки, и передаются они аналогично. А `sun()` - вызов функции.

```js
function sun() {
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
return x; }

function mult(func) {
var x = 5 + func();
return x}

console.log(mult(sun))
```

Comment: "Функции в js ... это обычные строки" - :D